# How to load a module outside modules folder on HMVC with CodeIgniter?

Tags: codeigniter, module, hmvc

Since I didn't find it anywhere else on the net, I hope I'm not asking a stupid question.

So I have this structure on my app:

```
My APP
|_
  Controllers
|_
  Modules
  |_
    bar
  |_
    foo
|_
  Views
```

I can load the bar module on the foo's views using this code:

```
<?php echo Modules::run('bar/bar/index'); ?>
```

But I'm unable to load the same module on MyAPP views using the code above.

What am I missing? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Silly me, I was extending CI_Controller instead of MX_Controller on all my controllers outside the modules folder. Hope this helps someone else.

Answer (score 1):

Well you can do this too

```
<?php echo Modules::run('../bar/bar/index'); ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you extended the MX_controller in your inside module controller it will automatically render the view from the root view folder files.