# showing a module anywhere in website of codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am pretty new to codeigniter and working on an audio cart website.

I implemented a audio playlist in my project and I created a different module called  **playlist**. Created routes and everything working fine for the page [playlist](http://webcartz.stagetesting.com/playlist). I used HMVC codeigniter and hence i have different folders for each module.

My playlist is basically a list of songs and user can select and play any song.

```
 Modules-
    ---Playlist
       --Controllers
         --playlist.php (my front controller)           
       --Models 
         --playlistmodel.php (model)  
       --Views
         index.php (view for showing playlist)
```

Now according to new specifications, This playlist can be placed anywhere in the website. It should be working. I am not able to figure out how is this feasible ? should I need to create helpers ?

Please help .

Live Url : http://webcartz.stagetesting.com/playlist

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

see this url:--

[How to load a module outside modules folder on HMVC with CodeIgniter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11256372/how-to-load-a-module-outside-modules-folder-on-hmvc-with-codeigniter)

Well you can do this too

```
<?php echo Modules::run('../bar/bar/index'); ?>
```

Comment: Thanks Abid , I will try and will be back to you.

Comment: Okk..Abid. what it will be in my case ?? I mean run command ?

Comment: see this url https://bitbucket.org/wiredesignz/codeigniter-modular-extensions-hmvc/wiki/Home

Comment: I tried using echo Modules::run("../playlist/playlist/index"); but did not find it working....

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/15462/discussion-between-vikas-and-abid-hussain)

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you should create a library then

> When we use the term "Libraries" we are normally referring to the
>   classes that are located in the libraries directory and described in
>   the Class Reference of this user guide. In this case, however, we will
>   instead describe how you can create your own libraries within your
>   application/libraries directory in order to maintain separation
>   between your local resources and the global framework resources.
>
> As an added bonus, CodeIgniter permits your libraries to extend native
>   classes if you simply need to add some functionality to an existing
>   library. Or you can even replace native libraries just by placing
>   identically named versions in your application/libraries folder.

http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/creating_libraries.html

something like this

```
class Playlistlib {

public function __construct($params)
{
    $CI =& get_instance(); // so you'd use $CI instead of $this to ref to CI object
    // Do something with $params
}

public function get_playlist($params)
{
    // Do something with $params
}

}

$params = array('id' => 15, 'limit' => 5);

$this->load->library('Playlistlib', $params);
```